# Twilio React JS Integration

Tags: reactjs, npm, twilio

I am trying to integrate Twilio into React using the documentation: https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-a-custom-video-chat-app-with-react-and-twilio-programmable-video

As mentioned in the document I cloned the GIT Repo and tried installing it.

```
git clone https://github.com/ahl389/twilio-video-starter-kit
cd twilio-video-starter-kit
npm install
```

When I try to install I am getting a long list of errors.

```
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.3: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
⸨##################⸩ ⠴ reify:typescript: timing reifyNode:node_modules/rxjs Completed in 38945ms
```

The installation will hang for some time at this point and finally another set of errors occur

```
-W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/operators.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/operators.o ../src/libsass/src/operators.cpp
npm ERR!   c++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/Users/macbook/.node-gyp/16.10.0/include/node -I/Users/macbook/.node-gyp/16.10.0/src -I/Users/macbook/.node-gyp/16.10.0/deps/openssl/config -I/Users/macbook/.node-gyp/16.10.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/Users/macbook/.node-gyp/16.10.0/deps/uv/include -I/Users/macbook/.node-gyp/16.10.0/deps/zlib -I/Users/macbook/.node-gyp/16.10.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -O3 -gdwarf-2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -arch x86_64 -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fno-strict-aliasing -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/output.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/output.o ../src/libsass/src/output.cpp

..... Lots of Similar Errors.....

npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/macbook/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/macbook/REACT/twilio-video-starter-kit/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.10.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.16
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.10.0
npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.10.0' ]
npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "16.10.0"
npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 16.10.0
npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good
npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 16.10.0
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/macbook/REACT/twilio-video-starter-kit/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /Users/macbook/REACT/twilio-video-starter-kit/node_modules/node-sass/build
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /Users/macbook/REACT/twilio-video-starter-kit/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
npm ERR! (node:62179) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/macbook/REACT/twilio-video-starter-kit/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/macbook/REACT/twilio-video-starter-kit/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/macbook/REACT/twilio-video-starter-kit/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/macbook/REACT/twilio-video-starter-kit/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/macbook/REACT/twilio-video-starter-kit/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/macbook/.node-gyp/16.10.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/macbook/.node-gyp/16.10.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/macbook/REACT/twilio-video-starter-kit/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/macbook/.node-gyp/16.10.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',

..... Lots of Similar Errors.....
```

(I can't even paste all the errors here - word limit)

I tried removing packages from **package.json** file, and found out(I think) the main issue is with

```
"node-sass": "^4.14.1"
```

This version of **node-sass** is not compatible with node version(latest version) which I have installed in my system which is

```
macbook@Macbooks-MacBook-Air ~ % node -v
v16.10.0
```

Kindly suggest me to what to do next as I don't know what to do next.
I can't change the node version to a previous one. Need to run in the latest version.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [node-sass package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) suggests that the Node 16 is supported in node-sass version 6+. So, install the latest version of `node-sass` (`npm i node-sass@latest`) or update the package.json dependency to `"node-sass": "^7.0.1"` and then try a full install again (`npm install`).

**Edit**

I had to perform a couple of extra steps to get this to work.

1. Add `"node-sass": "^7.0.1"` as the dependency in `package.json`
2. Install `react-scripts` version 4.0.3: `npm install react-scripts@4.0.3`
3. Rebuild `node-sass` with `npm rebuild node-sass`
4. Start the application with `npm start`

You could even investigate updating `react-scripts` to the latest version 5.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I did that. But still showing error. Now when I start the app

```
Failed to compile

./src/App.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/App.scss)
Error: Node Sass version 7.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with the steps I just took to get this application running.

Comment: wow.. Thanks philnash. It worked. Can you tell me on how did you come to this conclusion? Like install react-scripts@4.0.3?

Comment: Sure, I updated `node-sass` as I originally suggested then ran the application and saw the error you saw. The error was suggesting that the version of `node-sass` and `sass-loader` did not match up. I went to check npm for the dependencies of `react-scripts` and `sass-loader` was among them. At version 4.0.0, `sass-loader` v8 was a dependency, at version 4.0.3 `sass-loader` v10 was a dependency, so I tried updating `react-scripts` to 4.0.3 to see if it helped and it did. To keep up in the future, you might want to bring `react-scripts` up to v5, but that might take more work.

Comment: How did you know the dependency version? Like when I check `react-scripts` it says `sass-loader` is a dependency. But how did you find out v8 or v10 is the dependency for each `sass-loader`. I am just curious. I really want to learn this. Thanks

Comment: If you go to the [`react-scripts` repo](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/main/packages/react-scripts) (as part of the `create-react-app` monorepo) you can choose a tag (such as [4.0.3](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/v4.0.3/packages/react-scripts)) and then check the [`package.json` file for the dependencies](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v4.0.3/packages/react-scripts/package.json#L79).